# AngularJS .destroy() shows console error, but works?

Tags: angularjs

I use `destroy()` function something like this:

```
$scope.Cities[i].destroy();
```

Then when I use it my app works fine, but the console says:

```
$scope.Cities[i] is undefined
```

However without it, it doesn't work. Should I ignore the error?

**MORE CODE**

```
$scope.Somefunction= function (id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Cities.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.Cities[i] == id) {
            $scope.SpliceCities(i);
            $scope.Cities[i].destroy();

        } 
    }

    $scope.SpliceCities = function(i) {
        $scope.Cities.splice(i, 1);
    };
}
```

Function is called on ng-click on country.

Comment: What is going on? Where's the code? We have 0 context and we can't help you!

Comment: @Cinch there is nothing un-ordinary in my code but here..

Comment: Isamovic That's not the point. The point is that having zero code with no context and just a short question can be perceived as low quality and can lead to a question ban.

Comment: @Cinch Added my AngularCode

Comment: @AlminIslamovic what you wanted to do using `.destroy()` there is no such method as `.destroy()` on scope variables..

Comment: @pankajparkar well, if I remove .destroy() it doesn't remove my id or item from scope. it is still shown in HTML. Which is weird.. and when i put destoy it works.. .destroy() is an Jquery function i think?

Comment: @AlminIslamovic as you are expecting..there is no such thing in angularjs..what exactly you want to do..

Comment: Have you tried `delete  $scope.Cities[i];`  ?

Comment: @NLN yeah, the funny thing is it reports that delete is not possible and just breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splice` mutates the array, so the `i` index points to another element when calling `destroy()`. If `i` pointed to the last element before the splice, you get this error. Fortunately `splice` also returns the elements that were spliced out as an array, so try this:

```
$scope.Somefunction = function (id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Cities.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.Cities[i].id == id) {
            var spliced = $scope.Cities.splice(i, 1);
            spliced[0].destroy();
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: it.. "works" is deletes it everything is fine but the same console error: **spliced is undefined**

Comment: If you did not forget the `var` before `spliced`, it means that it needs to break the loop after the data is destroyed. The reason is the same as that of the answer, after the splice `i` points to the wrong element.

Comment: edited, and nothing same error again.. i tried to make spliced global variable, nothing.. error persists :/

Comment: You probably have to post a fiddle/plunk.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nYW1ecxMgfKW1MVXX4iv 

its not working for some reason but this is the code..

Comment: The code you posted is NOT the code above; above it calls `$scope.Cities.splice()`, while in the plunk it calls `$scope.Splice()`. And of course you cannot compare the id with the entire object. Also the plunk did not work because there was no `ng-app`. Anyway, [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rm9FdvSoLD4JSj7tPHYU?p=preview) it is, corrected.